# Number of Anomalies generated in Bucket Span [X-PACK]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, data-analysis, xpack

Sorry for the newbie question but i am new to Elastic products. I am learning X-Pack from Tutorials by Elastic. So while watching [this video](https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1497898493~acl=%2A%2F772374398.mp4%2A~hmac=6d2e0e5f39577ea4f0ccbbb869ff74220fc5348f65576f9c7c1d63253b9fcd46/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/4175/8/220877615/772374398.mp4) tutorial on Investigating Anomalies in dataset using Kibana and X-Pack i got confused(though i answered them correct) while answering these two questions.

[image]

I understand that there can be unlimited anomalies in a bucket but can someone explain me why only one anomaly is generated for a bucket span, I am not able to understand the explanation provided by Elastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the quiz should have read:

> How many anomaly scores are generated for each bucket span?

I have updated it to reflect that.

There is a single score but an unlimited amount of anomalies that can be found in each bucket span.  Sorry for the confusing text in the quiz question!

Comment: I created the course they are talking about. I posted this to let them it has been changed. I don't know how that "does not answer the question".

Comment: Sorry about that - I misread the answer.  I retracted my flag and upvoted, and edited to make it a little more clear what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck at the same point wondering the same thing, these 2 questions definitely seem to contradict one another. After rewatching the video it became clear that for each bucket span there is only one anomaly score provided, but this can be derived from any number of anomalies (1 to unlimited) having occurred in the data within that bucket span. Hence why I opted to answer question 1 with 1 and 2 with unlimited.

If this is indeed the case then it either implies the wording of the first question is wrong and should actually read something like:

> How many anomaly scores are generated for each bucket span?

Or maybe it's an intentional trick question, to make sure people are paying attention.